# Letter recognition is super inaccurate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to make a neural network that classifies letters. I have it training and it gets to 96% accuracy but when I get it to classify things, it either guesses correctly or guesses R. When I try to get it to print out the certainty it is always low (the highest I've seen is 22%) and whenever it guesses R (unless its actually R) it says 17% accuracy.

Here is the full code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

word_dict = {0:'A',1:'B',2:'C',3:'D',4:'E',5:'F',6:'G',7:'H',8:'I',9:'J',10:'K',11:'L',12:'M',13:'N',14:'O',15:'P',16:'Q',17:'R',18:'S',19:'T',20:'U',21:'V',22:'W',23:'X', 24:'Y',25:'Z'}
a = input("Would you like to train a new model ('train'), evaluate the current one ('evaluate'), run the current one ('run'), or exit the program ('exit)? ")
while(a!="exit"):
    
    if(a.lower()=="train"):

        data = pd.read_csv(r"training_data.csv").astype('float32')

        X = data.drop('0',axis=1)
        Y = data['0']

        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.2)

        x_train = np.reshape(x_train.values, (x_train.shape[0], 28, 28))
        x_test = np.reshape(x_test.values, (x_test.shape[0], 28, 28))

        shuff = shuffle(x_train[:100])

        x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)

        x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2], 1)

        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))

        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))

        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=26, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


        model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4)

        model.save('handwritting.model')

        accuracy, loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
        print("the accuracy is: ", accuracy)
        print("The loss is: ", loss)
    elif(a.lower()=="evaluate"):
        data = pd.read_csv(r"training_data.csv").astype('float32')
        X = data.drop('0',axis=1)
        Y = data['0']
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.2)
        x_test = np.reshape(x_test.values, (x_test.shape[0], 28, 28))
        shuff = shuffle(x_train[:100])
        x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2], 1)
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('handwritting.model')
        accuracy, loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
        print("the accuracy is: ", accuracy)
        print("The loss is: ", loss)
    elif(a.lower()=="run"):
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('handwritting.model')
        a2 = input("What is the filename of the png image?")
        
        img = cv2.imread(f"{a2}")[:,:,0]
        img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
        prediction = model.predict(img)
        print(f"This letter is {word_dict[np.argmax(prediction)]}")
        print(f"The program is {np.argmax(prediction).round()}% certain")
    a = input("Would you like to train a new model ('train'), evaluate the current one ('evaluate'), run the current one ('run'), or exit the program ('exit)? ")
```

Here is a link to a google doc with the code, training data, and test images that I used in case you want to try it out with the exact same setup as me: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p4CAHc-YrcQ8XPO7k539Z4giKLk-xIsV?usp=sharing

Comment: All information and code has to be in the question as text, not as external links.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy oh I didn't know that. I added it.

Comment: What IS that training data?  Where did it come from?  Are those bitmaps?

Comment: And, by the way `while`, `if` and `elif` statements in Python do not use extra parentheses.  They are not functions.  That's a bad habit left over from C and C++.

Comment: @TimRoberts found it on kaggle. heres the link. https://www.kaggle.com/sachinpatel21/az-handwritten-alphabets-in-csv-format

Comment: CrossValidated might be a better place to ask these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to up your epochs you are currently training for a very short time. I suspect your model maybe isn't converging after just 4 Epochs...try setting it higher. For example

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

Watch if your loss is improving or if it just sits at the same the whole traiing period.

Another thing you can do to prefent overfitting during training is to include dropout layers in your model. For example

```
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=26, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

Let me know if this helps I will test it when I get home later.

Comment: epoch 6 is the last epoch where I see significant improvement (after that some epochs even get worse than the previous one). It ends up floating around 93.25% accuracy and 0.33 loss. I am only 11 epochs in and I will run it overnight to see what it ends up with and either add a new comment or edit this one with what happens

Comment: Also make shure that when you do a single predict in your last `elif` that you prepare the images like you prepare the train and testdate ;)

Comment: also, lowering the learning factor in .compile might help

Comment: This didn't work. it got 1 out fo the 9 I tried correct after trying both your and @rikyeah suggestion

Comment: So I set up your project and I'm pretty shure that your Datapreparation of your images is not the same when you load the single images in comparison to your train data.
How did you get the csv. Do you have the code for this?